# Android GraphicsView enbbeded in layout

Tags: android

How to enbbed a GraphicsView into a layout? Or how do I add buttons and textViews to a GraphicsView? Could some one post a simple working example?

-Henry

Comment: Isn't that `GraphicsView` a custom class created by you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add other `View`s inside a View component.
`GraphicsView` is not a default Android SDK class, so we can't know what you have there, sorry.

Make a `Layout` component to be able to add `View` components inside it.

To embed your `GraphicsView` in a layout in xml use something like:

```
<com.package.GraphicsView
    id="@+id/graphics"
    ...
/>
```